# Problems using each function to read ajax values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following problem:

I'm trying to style with red border fields whose value is empty with the following jQuery code:

```
$("#frmId input, #frmId select, #frmId textarea").each(function(){
      if($(this).val() == ""){
          $(this).css('border', '1px solid red')
      }
});
```

The problem is that the fields that are loaded by ajax through the value of another field selected are being identified as empty and applying the red border, even if the field contains value.

The field values ​​are populated as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
       //POPULATE FIELDS
       $("#sltStatusProcesso").val('<?php echo $rstDados['ind_status'] ?>').prop('selected', true);   
        $("#sltUltimoCargo").val('<?php echo $rstDados['cod_cargo'] ?>').prop('selected', true);
        $("#sltClassificacaoFunc").val('<?php echo $rstDados['cod_class_funcionario'] ?>').prop('selected', true);
        $("#sltClassificacaoFunc").val('<?php echo $rstDados['cod_class_funcionario'] ?>').prop('selected', true);
        $("#sltTipoDesligamento").val('<?php echo $rstDados['cod_tipo_desligamento'] ?>').prop('selected', true);
        $("#sltVara").val('<?php echo $rstDados['cod_vara'] ?>').prop('selected', true);
        $("#sltUF").val('<?php echo $rstDados['cod_uf'] ?>').prop('selected', true);
        $("#sltUnidade").val('<?php echo $rstDados['cod_unidade'] ?>').prop('selected',true);
        setTimeout("carregaComarcas('<?php echo $rstDados['cod_comarca'] ?>')", 1);
        setTimeout("carregaComplementosUnidades($('#sltUnidade').get(), '<?php echo $rstDados['cod_unidade'] ?>')", 1);
        setTimeout("carregaComplementosComarca($('#sltComarca').get(), '<?php echo $rstDados['cod_comarca'] ?>')", 1);
        $("#sltTurmaTRT").val("<?php echo $rstDados['num_turma_trt'] ?>").prop('selected', true);
        $("#sltTST").val("<?php echo $rstDados['dsc_tst'] ?>").prop('selected', true);
        $("#sltTurmaTST").val("<?php echo $rstDados['num_turma_tst'] ?>").prop('selected', true);
        $("#sltFaseProcesso").val("<?php echo $rstDados['cod_fase_processo'] ?>").prop('selected', true);
        $("#sltClassificacaoDecisao").val("<?php echo $rstDados['cod_class_decisao'] ?>").prop('selected', true);

        //APPLY RED BORDER FOR EMPTY FIELDS
        $("#frmEditarProcessos input, #frmEditarProcessos select, #frmEditarProcessos textarea").each(function(){
          if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid red')
          }
        });
 });

function carregaComplementosUnidades(sltUnidade, intCodUnidade){
  var intUnidade = intCodUnidade ? intCodUnidade : sltUnidade.value;
    $.post("carregaComplementosUnidade.php",{intCodUnidade : intUnidade}, function(objJson){
    $("#sltEmpresa").val(objJson.intCodEmpresa).prop('selected', true);
    $("#txtEmpresa").val(objJson.strEmpresa);
    $("#sltGeo").val(objJson.intCodGeo).prop('selected', true);
    $("#txtGeo").val(objJson.strGeo);
    $("#sltMundo").val(objJson.intCodMundo).prop('selected', true);
    $("#txtMundo").val(objJson.strMundo);
  },"json");
}
```

The fields loaded by carregaComplementosUnidades function and the other functions are those with the problem.

What can be happening?

Tks.

Comment: You need to only fire that code *after* your AJAX code has populated the values.

Comment: you need to call this code in the callback of your ajax. Pls provide us with the ajax call as well so that we can help you further if this isn't clear.

Comment: If you posted your code, then you can get the solutions easily.

Comment: you have forget to post in which context this code is called

Comment: Are you giving same id to multiple elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your code in a function:

```
function checkFields() {
    $("#frmId input, #frmId select, #frmId textarea").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid red')
        }
    });
}
```

And then call this function **after** AJAX completes, when the values are in the input fields:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'myUrl.php',
    complete: function() {
        checkFields(); // this will highlight empty fields AFTER ajax has finished
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery code is evaluated just once and is not called dynamically after some values in input boxes change. Probably you call your code on document load and that time AJAX call has not yet returned and your input boxes are empty. They got filled up afterwards, but your code is not called anymore and style is not updated.

You have to do two things:

1. Move your code to seperate function and call it on document load and also in callback of AJAX call;
2. Change function to remove red border if the value is not empty;

If you want dynamic evaluation of rules then you should use frameworks like KnockoutJS, AngularJS